# Proper technical terms and sentence structure regarding web apps

Tags: terminology, programming, technical, software

Could you help me with a particular sentence in English? I am not a native speaker.

I am writing about my company from our official twitter account where mistakes are not forgiven. I want to say that we are moving from one software release model to another and I need it to be short (below 100 chars).

Currently I have a sentence like this:

> We have set aside the cloud-based version of XXX and will simply offer a standalone app. What do you think?

*XXX* is the name of our product.

I googled some parts and different variations of the sentence and there were very few results which lead me to think that there is something wrong. The specific parts I have trouble with – "standalone app" and "cloud-based version". Is it considered slang? What about "self-hosted web app"?

Sometimes I over-think stuff like this and can't decide what's right or wrong.

Comment: Both "standalone app" and "cloud-based version" are fine. What's strange is the "set aside". You probably mean something like "discontinued", or "forgot about", or "buried the plans for", whichever applies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Couldn't have guessed that there is something wrong with "set aside". Yes, I wanted to say that the cloud-based version is discontinued in favor of standalone app (which is a good thing, because that is what customers want). Is there something shorter than "discontinued" that could be used?

Comment: It's not that there is "something wrong" with *set aside*. It's that it's not clear what you mean by that. You want to say *discontinued* or *dropped* or *deprecated* or *no longer supported*. Among terms such as these it depends what you mean. It depends whether you are talking about a released product that is supported or you are talking about current development of something that has not yet been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

*We are retiring the cloud-based version of XXX and will only offer a standalone app.*

This is eighty four characters and the verbiage would be understood by your readers.

**EDIT#1**

based on your comments, consider:

*We are deferring the development of a cloud-based version of XXX and will offer a standalone app.*

This communicates your current intent.  It leaves open the possibility of a future cloud-based version.  It is ninety seven characters.

Comment: Thanks! Your version sounds good. I tried to put some benefit to the standalone version with the word "simply".

Comment: A small thing about the "retiring" vs "set aside". I used (incorrectly) "set aside", because I didn't want to reject the possibility to offer the cloud-based version in future, but "retiring" is a pretty strong word, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on what is actually going to happen.  If the cloud-based version will no longer be available, then I would use *retire.*  It is important to alert your readers so they will migrate to the standalone version.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that the product is not currently launched, but will be soon. Earlier we made a statement that there will be both - a standalone and cloud version of our product, but people were only excited for a standalone version and there were some principal issues with a cloud-based solution. Now we are announcing that the plans have changed and initially we will only launch the standalone app. The change also means that all our effort and focus will be put on the standalone version.

Comment: **Excellent** - based on your comment *retire* is **not** correct.  I will update the post.

Comment: Thanks for the updated version, looks great! One tiny thing - could I add "and will only offer" or "and will initially offer", or something like that?

Comment: Yes... these phrases improve clarity without adding much to the character count.